# Android bitmap does either work in landscape or portrait

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-camera2

I want to show an Image in an `ImageView`.

I do it this way:

```
    File externalDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File directory = new File (externalDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
    File file = new File(directory, "pic.jpg"); //or any other format supported

    FileInputStream streamIn = null;
    try {
        streamIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn); //This gets the image

    try {
        streamIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The problem is that if I start the application in landscape and rotate the device afterwards, the application crashes.

Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The next problem is that the picture isn't shown in fullscreen.
Do you have any suggestions to solve these issues?

> LOGCAT WHEN ROTATING THE DEVICE

```
01-03 11:23:45.810 25429-25429/com.kamera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.kamera, PID: 25429
                                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 80683020 byte allocation with 16765280 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
                                                                       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:649)
                                                                       at com.kamera.PhotoActivity.loadImageFromExternalStorage(PhotoActivity.java:47)
                                                                       at com.kamera.PhotoActivity.onCreate(PhotoActivity.java:29)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4398)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: post the logcat error details always

Comment: Ok I have added it now

Comment: you need to apply `BitmapFactory.Option` while decoding your stream because your bitmap is taking too much memory due to big size

Comment: Resize Your Bitmap .

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: [go through links](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=apply+bitmap+options+android&rlz=1C1AOHY_enIN717IN717&oq=apply+bitmap+options+android&aqs=chrome..69i57.10639j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: You can also try the image download by using this ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9288544/6417949

Answer (score 1):

Resize bitmap(Take care you don't lose too much quality. Change the value of sample size according to need)

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
```

and put **android:allowBackup="true"**  in your manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

for full screen image use:

android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Ok thanks works better now! How do I show the image in fullscreen in landscape/portrait mode? That doesn't work properly

Comment: @mafioso I updated the answer. This will work both in conditions landscape and portrait.

Comment: I've already set allowBackup to true but in landscape mode the picture is still not fullscreen

Comment: Are you changing your layout in landscape mode? I just checked the code and its working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

1. To avoid out of memory issue, Refer the below link for scaling the bitmap
   https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.
2. To display the image in full screen add " android:scaleType="fitXY" " in your xml file inside image tag.

Comment: Thanks, works for portrait mode but in landscape mode it is still the same..  Do you know why?

Comment: Whether your view is recreating when you changing the orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you rotate the device then O.S. recreates the activity and all it's objects are created/ initialized. Suppose you started the application and your device is in portrait mode, Your bitmap is loaded and processed at memory. When you rotate the device, the bitmap is again decoded to memory from your storage.

Solution :-  1. Keep the bitmap reference global.
             2. At savedInstanceState() or onCreate() check for bitmap is processed or not. If processed then need not to process it again.

Example.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(null != savedInstanceState && null != bitmap) {
         // Bitmap is processed already.
}
else {
        // Bitmap is not processed. Need to process it. 
}
}
```

Or Check the same at onSaveInstanceState() method.

Comment: bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn); //This gets the image
this line get executed everytime and loads bitmap in memory again and again.